# sprite doesnt detect collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm new to sprite kit and I'm working in Swift. Trying to get collision detected when hero collides with rightwall. I can detect collision when hero collides with everything else but for some reason it wont detect right wall.

Again hero will detect collision with left wall but nothing happens with right wall.
i'm stumped...

### in my gamescene this is how i set everything up

```
    class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    enum contactType: UInt32 {
            case heroCategory = 1
            case fireCategory = 2
            case rightTrapCategory = 4
            case leftTrapCategory = 8
            case leftWallCategory = 16
            case rightWallCategory = 32
        }


        let leftTrap = SKSpriteNode()
        let rightTrap = SKSpriteNode()
        let fire = SKSpriteNode()
        let hero = SKSpriteNode()
        let leftWall = SKSpriteNode()
        let rightWall = SKSpriteNode()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


        addLeftWall()
        addRightWall()
        addFire()
        addHero()
        addLeftTrap()
        addrightTrap()

}
```

### This is where i detect, sort and act on those collisions.

```
func collision(between Hero: SKNode, object: SKNode) {



    switch object.name {
    case "fire":
        addHighscore()
        destroy(hero: Hero)
        gameOver()
    case "rightTrap":
        jumpCounter = 0
        hero.color = .cyan
        print("right trap")
    case "leftTrap":
        jumpCounter = 0
        hero.color = .cyan
        print("left Trap")
    case "leftWall":
        hero.color = .red
        print("left wall")
    case "rightWall":
        hero.color = .red
        print("right wall")
    default:
        print("something went wrong")
    }




}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {

        collision(between: contact.bodyA.node!, object:contact.bodyB.node!)

    }else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask{

        collision(between: contact.bodyB.node!, object: contact.bodyA.node!)

    }


}
```

### How I set up the sprites

```
func addHero(){

        hero.name = "hero"
        hero.zPosition = 1
        hero.color = .cyan
        hero.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 50)
        hero.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: (frame.midY + 100))



        hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 25, height: 50))
        hero.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
        hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactType.heroCategory.rawValue


        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.fireCategory.rawValue

        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.leftTrapCategory.rawValue
        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.rightTrapCategory.rawValue

        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.rightWallCategory.rawValue
        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.leftWallCategory.rawValue


        addChild(hero)


    }


 func addRightWall(){

        rightWall.name = "rightWall"
        rightWall.color = .red
        rightWall.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: (frame.maxX / 2) + 25 )
        rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: (frame.midX + 200))
        rightWall.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)


        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: rightWall.size.width / 2 - (rightWall.size.width * rightWall.anchorPoint.x), y: rightWall.size.height / 2 - (rightWall.size.height * rightWall.anchorPoint.y))


        rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size, center: centerPoint)

        rightWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        rightWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactType.rightWallCategory.rawValue



        addChild(rightWall)


    }
```

### and just so you can see, left wall sprite.

again collision works with left wall but not the right one.

```
func addLeftWall(){

        leftWall.name = "leftWall"
        leftWall.color = .red
        leftWall.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: (frame.maxX / 2) + 25 )
        leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: (frame.midX + 200))
        leftWall.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)


        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: leftWall.size.width / 2 - (leftWall.size.width * leftWall.anchorPoint.x), y: leftWall.size.height / 2 - (leftWall.size.height * leftWall.anchorPoint.y))


        leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size, center: centerPoint)




        leftWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        leftWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactType.leftWallCategory.rawValue



        addChild(leftWall)



    }
```

Comment: Make a distinction between contact and collision.  They are not the same.

Comment: you're correct, my mistake labeling this as a collision issue.

Comment: You completely misunderstand my advise.  You'd better read your Sprite Kit book over.

Comment: You've made a statement such that you expect your nodes to collide with each other when in fact you are only using `contactTestBitMask` for that job.  So your question simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ElTomato The hero node is able to move around and collide with the other nodes. And I just want to know if the hero node is in contact with the nodes I listed.

I set each respective nodes to their category, then set the hero nodes contactTestBitMap to listen for each of the other nodes categories. 

This works and I am able to be notified when the hero comes in contact with fire, leftTrap, rightTrap, leftWall, however for some reason I am not able to get it to respond to my rightwall node

Comment: Nobody can help you when you don't even make a distinction between contact and collision.

Comment: @ElTomato I have made a distinction between contact and collision.
didBegin method listens for the SKPhysicsContact, then sorts that into bodyA and B then my collision method (yes I know i shouldnt have named it collision, but instead contact) then sorts out the contact by each nodes name. Works for everything else except rightwall.

Comment: So you actually want to observe contact between two nodes despite the title of your topic and the description?

Comment: You rewrite `contactTestBitMask` multiple times in `addHero()`, and as in usual assignment, only the last one is valid. So you can detect contacts only between `hero` and `leftWall`, The statement ___I can detect collision when hero collides with everything___ cannot be right, or you are not showing very important parts of your code.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks for your comment! Helped me realize what I didnt know and figured out that, first I cant assign a bunch of contactTestBitMasks like that, but instead have to have each one separated by a |. Still a lot to learn but this helps a lot. thanks

Answer (score 0):

### edit

I didnt realize I wasnt supposed to write it out like...

hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.fireCategory.rawValue

```
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.leftTrapCategory.rawValue
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.rightTrapCategory.rawValue

    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.rightWallCategory.rawValue
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.leftWallCategory.rawValue
```

But instead needed to separate each with an |

```
hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactType.fireCategory.rawValue | contactType.leftTrapCategory.rawValue | contactType.rightTrapCategory.rawValue |  contactType.rightWallCategory.rawValue | contactType.leftWallCategory.rawValue
```